# How to solve error: no such subcommand: `generate`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have installed rust using `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh` on Ubuntu.

But when I tried `cargo generate --git https://github.com/CosmWasm/cw-template.git --name FOO` I met the error like this `error: no such subcommand: 'generate'`

My cargo version is `cargo 1.59.0 (49d8809dc 2022-02-10)`.

Why this happens?

Answer (score 16):

You should install the `cargo-generate` with:

```
cargo install cargo-generate
```

Some cargo sub commands are built in, while others are installed separately. You can get the list of available sub commands with:

```
cargo --list
```

Comment: Note that the ‘others installed separately’ are also _unofficial._ A package’s name starting with `cargo-` doesn't mean anything about its authorship.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that even today `cargo add <package>` is not an official command. Its part of [cargo edit](https://lib.rs/crates/cargo-edit). It is going to be added in the next Rust update supposedly. For now you have to edit the `Cargo.toml` file the old fashioned way.

Edit: to install and have the ability to use add subcommand now, run `cargo install cargo-edit`

Comment: Are you sure it's part of cargo-edit? The docs list only four other subcommands that are installed this way. Maybe cargo generate is a dependency?

Comment: After I installed cargo-edit, I was able to successfully use the `add` subcommand, yes.